# Image texture with an alpha channel does not get packed

Tags: transparency, file-format, packed-data

When I pack my blender project I have a texture that uses an image texture (video) as the base colour (with an alpha channel, making the background of it transparent) and when I pack it, that specific image texture doesn't pack (prob cause of the file type). Is there any file format I should use for that image texture or workaround. I can send the file if u want but the texture wont be packed (unless I send both the packed file and video).

Comment: Videos can't be packed in Blender, only single images and sounds, so you probably need to extract the desired image?